# Hamburger icon both side with back arrow animation in toolbar for Two NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-design-library, navigationview

**First see the below screenshot and focus on the hamburger icon only so that you will get quick idea what I really want .?**

[image]

First of all I have successfully implemented the Navigation View(Drawer) to the both side left and right
So that user can open the two drawer from left & right both.

Now My question is **I want hamburger icon with animation to both side**.
I have implemented hamburger icon to the left side of toolbar which is easy and which comes by default. 
but now I want it to right side also with arrow animation.

1. Click on left hamburger icon open left drawer. (done)
2. click on right hamburger icon open drawer from right side. (it's remaining)

So Is it possible to have two hamburger icon on a single toolbar?

**Note: Both drawer are opening with gestures. and I don't have issue with it.**

Comment: No. Just No. Don't do it. Why?

Comment: I just want it. It's app requirement ..

Comment: The left drawer is usually intended for navigation. The right drawer can be used for content. You wouldn't want to confuse the user with 2 navigation drawers.

Comment: exectly. Left drawer is for navigation and right drawer is for content. I just want that it should open from right side icon. And i want that icon same as hamburger icon.

Comment: The burger icon is used for navigation. You should use another icon that is relevant to the content.

Comment: You should not have one icon image representing two different actions. That's confusing and illogical.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your opinions @BenitoBertoli...

Comment: Can you suggest me that which icon can be used for right drawer. ??

Comment: That really depends on what you're using the drawer for. Check out the [Material icons library](https://www.google.com/design/icons/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it using FrameLayout.

Now Consider the following layout

```
<FrameLayout>
     <Toolbar />
     <Toolbar layout_direction="right" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Using this the both toolbar will appear on top of each other.
Put drawer icon to both toolbar and the second toolbar will render it right side because we have specified layout direction to right.

**Note : Make the upper toolbar transparent.**

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library is what you looking for. It has `LEFT` and `RIGHT` modes.

Answer (score 1):

You can write animation which translates your right icon like this

While opening drawer **from x to x-someDelta**

and while closing drawer
**from x-somedelta to x**

**EDIT:**

You may use **[ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)** and its super class Value Animator

you can do something like this

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rightIcon, "translationX", 0,50); 

anim.start();
```

Use a boolean value and toggle it with 50,0 in the object animator to slide back

Also you can use **setDuration** method to set how long the animation should take to complete

Comment: Thaks for effort.. But i want default hamburger icon of android material